# How to convert dataframe new format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a  dataframe     :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'cell': ['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'A3', 'B2', 'B3', 'A4', 'B4'],
                   'site': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B']})

>>> df

  cell site
0   A1    A
1   A2    A
2   B1    B
3   A3    A
4   B2    B
5   B3    B
6   A4    A
7   B4    B
```

I want to get new format    :

```
A
A1
A2
A3
A4
B
B1
B2
B3
B4
```

Now I want to convert back this result ,but i am not able to do conversion.

Comment: HI! Welcome to [so]. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Well, I'm learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) and [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df.cell, df.site.drop_duplicates()]).sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
0     A
1    A1
2    A2
3    A3
4    A4
5     B
6    B1
7    B2
8    B3
9    B4
dtype: object
```

Or use `numpy methods` - [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) and [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
df = pd.Series(np.sort(np.concatenate([df.cell.values, df.site.unique()])))
print (df)
0     A
1    A1
2    A2
3    A3
4    A4
5     B
6    B1
7    B2
8    B3
9    B4
dtype: object
```

Another solution if `sorting` cannot be used - [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom function:

```
df =  df.groupby('site').cell
        .apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x.name] + x.values.tolist()))
        .reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
0     A
1    A1
2    A2
3    A3
4    A4
5     B
6    B1
7    B2
8    B3
9    B4
Name: cell, dtype: object
```

Comment: @piRSquared - good night, chores are unpleasent for me too ;)

Answer (score 1):

***option 1***
rubik's cube

```
print(
    df.groupby('site')
      .cell.apply(list)
      .apply(pd.Series)
      .reset_index()
      .stack()
      .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

***option 2***
comprehension

```
pd.Series(
    np.concatenate(
        [[name] + grp.tolist() for name, grp in df.groupby('site').cell]))
```

---

Both Yield

```
0     A
1    A1
2    A2
3    A3
4    A4
5     B
6    B1
7    B2
8    B3
9    B4
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print pd.melt(df).iloc[:, 1].drop_duplicates().sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)

0     A
1    A1
2    A2
3    A3
4    A4
5     B
6    B1
7    B2
8    B3
9    B4
```